# Properly size components inside auto expanding panel inside scrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on creating a form using Swing that programatically adds custom components into a ScrollPane such that the components have a fixed size and as more are added they are added below the previous and can be scrolled to.

I've been struggling to work with the various size functions in Swing. Currently I managed to programatically add child components into a panel in the scrollPane, and resize that panel as more children are added. However, the children currently attempt to fill the entire panel, shrinking as more children are added until they reach a minimum size. Only after reaching this minimum size does the panel expand to accomidate new components. I've played with various combinations of setSize and setPreferredSize but I've not been able to get it to work properly.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KvumrbJmEbbTNHTm9Lc3BGLTg/view?usp=sharing) is the form.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KvumrbJmEbYUVVY1BpdTR4UGM/view?usp=sharing) it is after one button click.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KvumrbJmEbcmRLTTRFbjBOZFk/view?usp=sharing) it is after two clicks.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KvumrbJmEbSk5uN0VXWmJuM1k/view?usp=sharing) it is after several clicks.

Here is a data object I am using for testing.

SimpleData.java

```
public class SimpleData {

    public SimpleData(String s0,String s1)
    {
        name = s0;
        ID = s1;
    }

    public String name;
    public String ID;

}
```

Here is the code for the component.

SimpleComponent.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Supplier;


public class SimpleComponent extends JPanel
{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel mainName;

    private JPanel sectionName;
    private JLabel labelName;
    private JTextField textName;

    private JPanel sectionID;
    private JLabel labelID;
    private JTextField textID;

    private SimpleComponent()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static SimpleComponent FromSimpleData(SimpleData data, Dimension size)
    {
        SimpleComponent ret = new SimpleComponent();

        BoxLayout lay = new BoxLayout(ret,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);

        ret.setLayout(lay);

        BiFunction<JPanel,String,JTextField> makeTextField =
                (JPanel p,String s) ->
                {
                    JTextField tf;
                    tf = new JTextField(s == null ? "" : s);
                    p.add(tf);
                    return tf;
                };

        BiFunction<JPanel,String,JLabel> makeLabel =
                (JPanel p,String s) ->
                {
                    JLabel jl;
                    jl = new JLabel(s);
                    p.add(jl);
                    return jl;
                };

        Supplier<JPanel> makePanel =
                () ->
                {
                    JPanel p;
                    p = new JPanel();
                    BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
                    p.setLayout(bl);
                    ret.add(p);
                    return p;
                };

        ret.mainPanel = makePanel.get();
        ret.mainName = makeLabel.apply(ret.mainPanel,data.name);

        ret.sectionName = makePanel.get();
        ret.labelName = makeLabel.apply(ret.sectionName,"Name:");
        ret.textName = makeTextField.apply(ret.sectionName,data.name);

        ret.sectionID = makePanel.get();
        ret.labelID = makeLabel.apply(ret.sectionID,"ID:");
        ret.textID = makeTextField.apply(ret.sectionID,data.ID);

        ret.setSize(size);
        ret.revalidate();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Here is the java code for the form.

SimpleGUI.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class simpleGUI {
    private JButton buttonAdd;
    private JPanel panelData;
    private JPanel panelMain;

    private static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("simpleGUI");

        simpleGUI sGUI = new simpleGUI();

        frame.setContentPane(sGUI.panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sGUI.panelData.setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(
                        sGUI.panelData,
                        BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        sGUI.buttonAdd.addActionListener(
                (e)->{
                    Dimension size = sGUI.panelData.getSize();

                     String id = Integer.toString(count++);
                     String name = "DATA-" + id;
                     SimpleData data = new SimpleData(name,id);

                    SimpleComponent component = SimpleComponent.FromSimpleData(
                            data,
                            new Dimension(
                              10,
                              10));

                    sGUI.panelData.add(component);

                    Dimension newSize = new Dimension(size.width,size.height * 2);
                    sGUI.panelData.setSize(newSize);

                    sGUI.panelData.validate();
                });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the form generated with InteliJ Idea.

SimpleGUI.form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="simpleGUI">
  <grid id="27dc6" binding="panelMain" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="2" column-count="1" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
    <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="500" height="400"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
    <children>
      <component id="4a868" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="buttonAdd">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Add"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <scrollpane id="29e66">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="1" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="7" hsize-policy="7" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <verticalScrollBarPolicy value="22"/>
        </properties>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children>
          <grid id="2d3af" binding="panelData" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="1" column-count="1" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
            <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
            <constraints/>
            <properties/>
            <border type="none">
              <color color="-16729344"/>
            </border>
            <children/>
          </grid>
        </children>
      </scrollpane>
    </children>
  </grid>
</form>
```

What can I do to accomplish the behavior I need?

Comment: You're essentially asking, "why is the code I'm not showing not working well", and you need to post a functioning [mcve] for a decent answer.

Comment: “I've played with various combinations of setSize and setPreferredSize…”  That’s your first problem.  Use a LayoutManager.  Don’t try doing it all manually.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels This code is as minimal as I could make it. I encountered these issues in a larger project and started from scratch, as the guidelines you linked indicate. I wrote the minimized code I linked in order to show exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @VGR Mind explaining how to accomplish that? I am using the BoxLayoutManager in order to stack the custom components above each other, what do I need to change in its usage in order to get it to properly size my components?

Comment: What code? You've posted no code as code-formatted text within your question. Note that code cannot be in links but again must be as code-formatted text in your question. Also it should be compilable and runnable. Please comment back once you've corrected this so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I moved the code into the question rather than linking.